# Changing keyboard layout on application focus

Tags: automation, keyboard

As everybody knows the en-US Keyboard-layout is the best one for programming. So I'd like to use it in my IDEs. But since I live in a non-en-US country I need the de-CH layout for all other applications. Now I wonder if it is possible to set the layout depending to which application currently has the focus. If that is possible, can a human brain adapt to such a behaviour or is it just confusing?

cheers,
AC

---

The operating system is Windows 7 and the IDEs are VisualStudio and Netbeans

Comment: What makes you think that en-US is the best layout for programming?

Comment: i like to differ. have you had a look at Neo? <http://neo-layout.org> i think it's by far superior to en-US

Comment: i think it's because of the arrangement af the braces and other special characters

Comment: Everyone can create a keyboard layout and gets used to it with MSKLC, if you are using Windows. It's a question of taste. In my case, I have mapped all the symbols to the upper number keys, and all paired symbols are located horizontally symmetrically to press with the same fingers with both hands. Do some DIY and you will find that US keyboard is not so friendly with programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thought about the same question some time ago, haven't fount an easy solution and so i changed the layout of may PC (where i do mostly programming) to en-US and left my Laptop on de-DE (i'm from germany) - after almost a week i changed back my PC to de-DE because i was confused ll the time...

Answer (score 1):

you should probably mention your operating system and ides. afaik there's an option to make the keyboard layout application specific – so you set it once after starting up your ide, and when you switch windows the layout is also changed.

nevertheless, have a look at ergonomic/optimized layouts (like [neo](http://neo-layout.org) ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in both Windows and Linux to use a US layout with additional international characters. For instance, typing an ä will be yielded by pressing RAlt+q. The good thing about this is that it's the same combination for Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can configure it easily with built-in Windows settings.

In "Control Panel" - "Clock, language and Region" - "Language", you can enable "Enable different input methods for each application window" (the translation is approximated because I am using Spanish OS). I think that suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own customized keyboard layout with [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator (MSKLC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx)

I used my current keyboard as base and modified only a few keys in order not to always twist my right thumb when I want to get curling bracktes `{}`

It works very well in combination with a short-cut for switching the keyboard layout. You can define such shortcut in your system language settings.